# How can I paint a specific line from a ClipPath?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, and I'm trying to imitate the shape on the left. I basically want to put the yellow border (as seen in the left image) over the blue figure at the top (the blue figure corresponds to the image on the right).

[image]

```
final double curve = 30.0;
final double heightShape = 200.0;

  class ClippingClass extends CustomClipper<Path> {
    @override
    Path getClip(
      Size size,
    ) {
      var path = Path();

      path.moveTo(0, 0);
      path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, curve, size.width / 2, curve);
      path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - (size.width / 4), curve, size.width, 0);
      path.lineTo(size.width, heightShape);
      path.lineTo(0, heightShape);
      path.close();
      return path;
    }

    @override
    bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
  }




  class Login extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
  }


  class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
    Login() {
      print("login page");
    }

  Widget shapeBottom(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
        clipper: ClippingClass(),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ));
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
                child: shapeBottom(context),
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                height: alturaForma),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How can I do it? apparently you can't do something simple like a border top or something.

was trying to duplicate the code and trying to put another figure that simulates having the shape of the border, but I don't get my desired effect.

thank you.

Comment: use `CustomPainter` and override its `paint()` method

Comment: @pskink thanks for your help,Excuse me, I'm very new to flutter, I don't know how this can help me with what I need.

Comment: check [Drawing Custom Shapes With CustomPainter in Flutter](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7560981-drawing-custom-shapes-with-custompainter-in-flutter)

Comment: @pskink thanks for your help, I saw the article, but in my case I don't know how to paint the top border .. :(  can you help me please?

Comment: it is `Canvas.drawPath(Path, Paint)` method that you should use

Comment: where? how? I am very confused..

Comment: inside `CustomPainter.paint` method - you have everything described in the link i posted - step `4. Then you implement paint(Canvas canvas, Size size). Flutter will call this method whenever the object needs to paint.` - read this carefully: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7560981-drawing-custom-shapes-with-custompainter-in-flutter#toc-anchor-007

Comment: I've updated the answer with custom painter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to embed the bottom shape in another container with same clipper, but with slightly larger height:

```
Widget shapeBottom(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: ClippingClass(),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
          child: ClipPath(
            clipper: ClippingClass(),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Result]

**Note:** It may not be the perfect solution, but it does the job. If you don't want to use another container, go for [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html)

```
class BottomSheetPainter extends CustomPainter {
  BottomSheetPainter({@required this.color, @required this.arcColor});
  final Color color;
  final Color arcColor;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = color;
    final arcPaint = Paint()..color = arcColor;

    // Whole area painter
    var path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, curve, size.width / 2, curve);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width - (size.width / 4), curve, size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, heightShape);
    path.lineTo(0, heightShape);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    // Arc Painter
    var arcPath = Path();
    arcPath.moveTo(0, 0);
    arcPath.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, curve, size.width / 2, curve);
    arcPath.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width - (size.width / 4), curve, size.width, 0);
    arcPath.lineTo(size.width, 30);
    arcPath.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width - (size.width / 4), 60, size.width / 2, 60);
    arcPath.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, 60, 0, 30);
    arcPath.close();
    canvas.drawPath(arcPath, arcPaint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(BottomSheetPainter oldDelegate) {
    return color != oldDelegate.color;
  }
}
```

And replace your `shapeBottom` with the following code:

```
Widget shapeBottom(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
      painter:
          BottomSheetPainter(color: Colors.blue, arcColor: Colors.yellow),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really my level of knowledge is not enough to try to do it in the best practice(CustomPainter)? if it's not too much trouble could you help me with that please? I just don't understand what to do.

Comment: @yavg: Sure, I'm trying out that right now. Will post the code once I finish it :)